# window.location removed the token from localStorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, redirect, local-storage, window.location

```
login(data){
    let appUrl = process.env.MIX_APP_PRO + process.env.MIX_APP_URL;
    axios.post('/api/auth/login', data)
    .then(res => {
        this.responseAfterLogin(res)
    })
    .then(dat => {
       let appUrl = '/hub';
       window.location = appUrl;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        if(error.response){
            Exception.handle(error.response.data)
        }
    })
}
```

```
responseAfterLogin(res){
    const access_token = res.data.access_token;
        const username = res.data.user;
        if(Token.isValid(access_token)){
            AppStorage.store(username, access_token);
        }
    }
}
```

Above are the functions that I am using in order to login a user in to my system and storing the access token to localStorage, The issue however is when user is redirected after successfull login the token some how get deleted from local storage.

Please Help.

```
import Token from "./Token";

class AppStorage{
    storeToken(token){
        window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    }

    storeUser(user){
        window.localStorage.setItem('user', user);
    }

    store(user, token){
        this.storeToken(token);
        this.storeUser(user);
    }

    clear(){
        window.localStorage.removeItem('user');
        window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
    }

    getToken(){
        return window.localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    getUser(){
        return window.localStorage.getItem('user');
    }

}

export default AppStorage = new AppStorage()
```

This is App storage class I am using to store and retrieve values in localStorage.

Comment: What is `AppStorage`?

Comment: AppStorage is the class I created to Store and Retriece values from Local Storage

Comment: Then please show us that class because the issue may well be in there.

Comment: I have added the class in question please have a look.

Comment: Another thing is this code actually works on my local host but when I upload on to the server thats where its deleting the values in localStorage

Comment: Have any body got change to look at the code and see what the problem is ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Guys this problem was solved, it was my mistake.

When I uploaded the site on the server I need to generate key for JWT key on time of installation of JWT Modules, which I didn't.

So the user was not logging in properly thats why token was being removed form localStorage as result of un-successful authentication.

Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is separated by protocol://host:port, so if you are redirecting to a page that has a different domain/subdomain you will not have access to the local storage that you populated

Comment: Judging from their code, it looks like they are redirecting to a url within the same host (`/hub`)

Comment: No the page is on same domain. But for some reason token is local storage gets deleted.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint before you navigate and make sure in the broswer that  your token is really stored? and when do you call the clear action in your AppStorage

Comment: This code is working on localhost. The problem only occur when I upload it on to the server.

Comment: Did anybody review the code and see what the problem is ?